# Github action curl request with env variables in body

Tags: github, github-actions

I tried many ways to put env variables in curl request, this is my current code in github action yaml.

```
- name: Send success notification
        env:
          COMMITER: ${{toJson(github.actor)}}
          COMMIT_MSG: ${{toJson(github.event.commits[0].message)}}
          COMMIT_TIME: ${{toJson(github.event.commits[0].timestamp)}}
          HEAD_COMMIT_MSG: ${{toJson(github.event.head_commit.message)}}
          REPO_NAME: ${{toJson(github.event.repository.full_name)}}
        if: ${{ success() }}
        run: |
          curl -X POST \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -d "{\"content\": \"Build Status: **SUCCESS**✅\nCommmit: `'$COMMIT_MSG'`\nCommit Time: `'$COMMIT_TIME'`\nCommiter: `'$COMMITER'`\nHead Commit: `'$HEAD_COMMIT_MSG'`\nRepo: `'$REPO_NAME'`\"}" \
            ${{secrets.DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL_SERVER_BUILD}}
```

The issue is env variables when popuplated are in double quotes eg.`COMMITER: "SAQLAIN"`, so when populated in curl it becomes like this `"{\"content\": \"Build Status: SUCCESS \n Commiter: "SAQLAIN" \"` So the quotes make it think that SAQLAIN is a command, hence there's an error command not found.

What could be the solution?
Thanks.

I tried using variables like $VAR and using them directly like $github.actor. Same problem i face.

Comment: Why do you need  §toJson§ here`${{toJson(github.actor)}}`. Please also make sure that `github.actor` doesn't have double quotes as a part of the value.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I was trying different ways, that's why in the process i tried putting toJson there, How can i remove double quotes from the variable values?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the same quotes in the request first, instead of using double quotes and then single quotes, so I would use only double quotes to make things simpler.

Also, In bash, to expand a variable in the string, it is recommended to wrap the variable in curly braces.

I have also a GitHub Actions workflow that sends a post request. The way I do it, and found it easy to maintain is by calling a simple bash script from the action itself, and passing it an env variable.
Later on, you can create a custom action which is probably the best practice in these cases.

GitHub Action:

```
- name: Send a post request
  run: |
    ./scripts/send_reuqest.sh ${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}
```

Script:

```
SERVICE_NAME=$1

# Create new github repo
curl -X POST "https://api.github.com/orgs/my-org/repos" \
    -u $GITHUB_USERNAME:$GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
    -d "{\"name\":\"${SERVICE_NAME}\",\"private\":\"true\"}"
```

Using the same structure should work for you, notice the escape characters and the curly braces around the variable.